# How can i make the image, text and button of the header responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am making a website using Bootstrap 5. In the header of the website, I am using a carousel from Bootstrap as my header. The carousel image allows for text and a button to be displayed as well. I want the image, text, and button to be responsive. I tried using media queries but I am not sure how to do it.

### Test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-Project/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="./assets/networking-connections-004.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
        </div> 
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
.c-item {
    height: 90%;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```css
.c-item {
    height: 90%;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-Project/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="./assets/networking-connections-004.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
        </div> 
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries read like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
 .carousel-inner{
  color:#000;
  }
}
```

I find with bootstrap, you'll have to add !important at the end for it to be read:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
 .carousel-inner{
  color:#000 !important;
  }
}
```

Try checking out this article for more on media queries:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

(Obviously you're probably not trying to change the font color, but it's just an example.)

Comment: thank you but it didn't work because when I put my ```c-item```, ```c-img```, and ```team-img``` classes under the media query ```@media screen and (min-width: 900px)``` on my phone I can't see the button. I can only see the header and intro tag